# How to change output type to input type in lightning onclick

Tags: lightning, lightninginput

I like to change output field type to input type when i click on date picker of date field.

Comment: What you have tried so far? Where did you get stuck? Please edit your question and add those details to it.

Answer (score 0):

Create an input field, and us the `disabled` attribute based on your date change. this will basically give you output like field properties, without the bloat.

For the date, use the  `ui:inputDate` component with the native date picker, and add a value change handler to retrieve date value change on the input field.  This sample will bind the date value to a value change handler.

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="myDate" type="Date" />
    <!-- Value change handler -->
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.myDate}" action="{!c.handleDateChange}"/>

    <ui:inputDate aura:id="mySelectedDate" 
                  label="Select a date" displayDatePicker="true" 
                  value="{!v.myDate}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Now that you have selected a date, and can handle an action. Suppose you want to make another input field disabled use the code below.

```
lightning:input disabled="{!v.disabledByDateChange}" value="initial value" label="Disabled text field with a predefined value" />
```